# How to display data that was extracted through the API (GET), using the Dropdown Button <T>

Tags: flutter, dart

I have little experience of fluttering, so I ask this question. I want to make a page through which I want to send data via POST to the database. On this page, I want to specify the type of operation (sealing or printing the object), the object ID, the data area, the photo, and the increased length. Data ID object, the type of operation I want to specify using a pop-up list. To begin with I made them 2. The first - a choice of type of operation (Sealing or Unsealing of object), and in the second pop-up list I would like to drag objects corresponding to operation (that is, if I want to seal object, I want show only unsealed objects). But I can't do that. I specify in the address code for which you want to get the data. I can't assign a "_myState" variable to "status". I will be grateful for your help.

```html
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _myState;
  @override


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Dynamic  REST API'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100, top: 100),
            child: Text(
              'Type seals',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w800, fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
          //======================================================== State

          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 5),
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                    child: ButtonTheme(
                      alignedDropdown: true,
                      child: DropdownButton<String>(
                        //value: _myState,
                        iconSize: 30,
                        icon: (null),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                        hint: Text('Select type'),
                        onChanged: (String newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            _myState = newValue;
                            _getObjectList();
                            print(_myState);
                          });
                        },
                        items: <String>['Seals', 'Unseals']
                            .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            value: value,
                            child: Text(value),

                          );
                        })?.toList() ??
                            [],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),

          //======================================================== City

          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 5),
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                    child: ButtonTheme(
                      alignedDropdown: true,
                      child: DropdownButton<String>(
                        value: _myObject,
                        iconSize: 30,
                        icon: (null),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                        hint: Text('Select object'),
                        onChanged: (String newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            _myObject = newValue;
                            print(_myObject);
                          });
                        },
                        items:  ObjectList?.map((item){
                          return new DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: new Text(item['name']),
                            value: item['data_area'].toString(),
                          );
                        })?.toList() ??
                            [],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  //=============================================================================== Api Calling here

//CALLING STATE API HERE
// Get State information by API


  // Get State information by API
  List ObjectList;
  String _myObject;

  String cityInfoUrl =
      'http:MyURL' + '?' + 'status=' + $_myState ;;
  Future<String> _getObjectList() async {
    await http.get(cityInfoUrl).then((response) {
      var data = json.decode(response.body);

  setState(() {
    ObjectList = data;
  });
});
    });
  }
}
```

The problem is that I do not understand what to insert in the index! , as well as another nuance, in the first list where I choose the type, I want to do so that when I choose Seal it returned "No", and if you unseal "Yes"
Here is my JSON that I want to display in the list:

```html
[
  {
    "name": "Object №1",
    "data_area": "4000",
    "sealed": "No"
  },
  {
    "name": "Object №2",
    "data_area": "4000",
    "decscription": "test",
    "sealed": "Yes",
    "longitude": "21.4342412",
    "latitude": "42.123131"
  },
  {
    "name": "Object №3",
    "data_area": "4000",
    "sealed": "Yes"
  }
]
```